# Boost.log caching records

Tags: c++, boost, logging, synchronous

I use Boost.Log for logging in my project and I have a problem.

After executing some code with log-events and just before exiting from program, the logfile written by boost.log is not complete. After exiting - it's ok, no record missing.

It's not good for me.

I don't use asynchronous version of logger.

Please, help - how I can make immediate writing into file with this library?

Comment: Hello, old question but I kept it in a bookmark because I'm interested in Boost.log. If your question is still pending, can you provide an example of code you use for logging, and any log configuration you may have used ?

Comment: Hi. I solved problem already: it was very stupid. In project we use configuration from file, which support boost.log. But we don't wrote into it string "Autoflush=true" and by default it was false. After adding this string logging became correct. But we found some mistake/bug in logic of boost.log - if you are interesting in it please write me into logachev.k at gmail.com

Comment: that's great. If you solved the problem, then answer your own question and mark it as "accepted". Boost.log is not yet mature (that's why it's not in boost yet) so I don't plan to use it eventually.